# Cordova/Phonegap shake gesture detection not working on ios simulator

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

i am just testing out this cordova plugin

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion/blob/master/doc/index.md

I added the plugin to the platform just did:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-motion
```

Then i am testing both on ios simulator and android 3.2 and android 4.1 real devices, but on IOS simulator seems not working, while on the real devices it works great.

Is there some limitation for IOS, or something i need to know? Or its just cause simulator can't emulate the shake gesture?

As you see from the pic there is a shake gesture emulation command :(

[image]

Unfortunately i don't have a real iphone or ipad, does anybody knows if on a real ios device this plugin works the same?

My code is as simple:

```
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
   navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(function (acceleration) {

        console.log('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');


      }, function (err) {

        console.log(err + ' --------watching err');
      }, {
        'frequency':1800
      });
   });
```

Comment: did you install the console plugin too?

Comment: @jcesarmobile nope, is that necessary to make this work? Android is doing console.logs on the adb logs...

Comment: @jcesarmobile installed , tryed, but no console logs by the simulator, looks like the simulator shake gesture emulation is not regarding the accelerometer i don't know :(

Comment: yes, on iOS you have to install the console plugin to see the console.log messages. Anyway, I've just tested your code and I confirm that I don't get mesages from the shake gesture either, but it works on a real device

Comment: great i'll wait for someother feedback that was my guess tho indeed, thank :)

Comment: I've been searching and I confirm that the simulator's shake won't be recognized by your code, the simulator shake just triggers the shake event, it doesn't update any accelerometer data.

Comment: @jcesarmobile great thanks, i'll be glad to accept it as an answer at this point :)

Comment: So is there anyway to test the shake function with the simulator?

Comment: You can create a plugin that listen for motion events https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simulator's shake won't be recognized by your code (or any accelerometer code), the simulator shake just triggers the shake event, it doesn't update any accelerometer data